# To add roaster and not getting displayed in openfire User Roaster list

Tags: api, rest, server, openfire

Add a roaster for user John using the api

http://openfire.test.net:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/John/roster

**Response Received: 201 Created**

When retreived roaster using Rest API - GET

http://openfire.test.net:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/John/roster

**Response Received: Status 200 OK**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<roster>
<rosterItem>
    <jid>roaster1@test.de</jid>
    <subscriptionType>0</subscriptionType>
    <groups/>
</rosterItem>
</roster>
```

But in Openfire Server UI, when clicked in User-> John and viewed Roster,no Rosters are displayed.Am I missing something in calling the Rest API? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.This is problem with the cases of the username.Even if you register with name 'John' from API, from the UI searches for 'john'.Therefore if did not show the Roasters initially.Later on it got resolved after changing the case.Hope this helps to all.